# Decompose mathematical expression into steps

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to know if there is a way to print each step considering python follows PEMDAS <sup>1</sup>. Can I make it print each step it does in solving this problem without building my own library?

```
print_steps('(3+7-2)*4/(3+32)')
```

<sup><sup>1</sup> Parentheses, Exponents, Multiplication and Division, and Addition and Subtraction</sup>

Comment: This code is a type error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "library" can be pretty lightweight:

```
class verbose_number:
    def __init__(self, value): self.value = value
    def operate(self, operator, other):
        other = getattr(other, 'value', other)
        result = eval('self.value %s other' % operator)
        print('%r %s %r = %r' % (self.value, operator, other, result))
        return self.__class__(result)
    def __add__(self, other): return self.operate('+', other)
    def __sub__(self, other): return self.operate('-', other)
    def __mul__(self, other): return self.operate('*', other)
    def __div__(self, other): return self.operate('/', other)
    def __floordiv__(self, other): return self.operate('//', other)
    def __truediv__(self, other): return self.operate('/', other)
    def __pow__(self, other): return self.operate('**', other)
    def __mod__(self, other): return self.operate('%', other)
    def __neg__(self): return self.__class__(-self.value)
    def __pos__(self): return self.__class__(+self.value)
    def __repr__(self): return repr(self.value)
    def __int__(self): return int(self.value)
    def __float__(self): return float(self.value)
```

Now any arithmetic computation that involves a `verbose_number` instance gets printed and returns another `verbose_number`, so the calculation is printed step by step:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> (verbose_number(3)+7-2)*4/(3+32)
3 + 7 = 10
10 - 2 = 8
8 * 4 = 32
3 + 32 = 35
32 / 35 = 0.9142857142857143
```

Note that this relied on the fact that I made the *first* number in the expression a `verbose_number`.  A refinement on the approach is to write a handy routine for parsing string expressions:

```
import re
def print_steps(expression):
    return eval(re.sub(r'([0-9\.]+([eE]-?[0-9]+)?)', r'verbose_number(\1)', expression))
```

This works by turning *every* numeric literal in the string into a `verbose_number` constructor call, thereby ensuring that *all* steps will be verbose no matter where Python's parser starts in the expression.  Here's how it can be used to evaluate your example:

```
>>> print_steps('(3+7-2)*4/(3+32)')
3 + 7 = 10
10 - 2 = 8
8 * 4 = 32
3 + 32 = 35
32 / 35 = 0.9142857142857143
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`ast.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse) and [`ast.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.dump) to get a grasp of it.

```
import ast
ast.dump(ast.parse('(3+7-2)*4/(3+32)', mode='eval'))
```

If formatted nicely, the output can look like this:

```
Expression(
  body=BinOp(
    left=BinOp(
      left=BinOp(
        left=BinOp(
          left=Num(n=3),
          op=Add(),
          right=Num(n=7)
        ),
        op=Sub(),
        right=Num(n=2)
      ),
      op=Mult(),
      right=Num(n=4)
    ),
    op=Div(),
    right=BinOp(
      left=Num(n=3),
      op=Add(),
      right=Num(n=32)
    )
  )
)
```

Inspired by jez's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40939926/12892) I came up with the following solution to transform the dump into some linear steps:

```
import operator
Expression = lambda body: body
Num = lambda n: n
USub = lambda : ('-', operator.neg)
Add = lambda : ('+', operator.add)
Sub = lambda : ('-', operator.sub)
Mult = lambda : ('*', operator.mul)
Div = lambda : ('/', operator.truediv)
FloorDiv = lambda : ('//', operator.floordiv)

def UnaryOp(op, operand):
    print(op[0], operand)
    result = op[1](operand)
    print(' =', result)
    return result

def BinOp(left, op, right):
    result = op[1](left, right)
    print(left, op[0], right, '=', result)
    return result

eval(ast.dump(ast.parse('(3+7-2)*4/(3+32)', mode='eval')))
```

It prints:

```
3 + 7 = 10
10 - 2 = 8
8 * 4 = 32
3 + 32 = 35
32 / 35 = 0.9142857142857143
```

[astviewer](https://github.com/titusjan/astviewer) can give you a graphical represention of the tree. For example `astviewer.main.view(source_code='(3+7-2)*4/(3+32)', mode='eval')` gives you:
[image: astviewer for 3+7-2)*4/(3+32)]

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Not even [`dis.dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.dis) will show you individual steps since it all gets simplified out to a single constant before being compiled to bytecode.

```
>>> def f():
...     return (3+7-2)*4/(3+32)
...
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST              10 (0.9142857142857143)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```